# recieveing Undefined index trying to get the key

Tags: php

Hi I’m trying to recieve data and i get the error Notice: Undefined index:['my key']

my php codes:

```
$Username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$Password = $_REQUEST['password'];
```

the code i'm sending:

```
{
  "username":"sss",
  "password":"aaa"

}
```

exact error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\android.dev\first_page.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\android.dev\first_page.php on line 34
```

Comment: you decoded the json before trying to use it right?

Comment: How are you sending it?

Comment: im sending it with asynchttppost and no cause the tutorial im watching it dosn't 
and the problem is i just open my php file and i have this error without sending anything....isn't my syntax trying to receive the key the problem?